# @@ Variables not working in Synapse Dedicated SQL pool (@@error, @@rowcount, etc.,)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

We are working on DW to Synapse migration. In that I am migrating an Stored Procedure which having @@error, @@rowcount variables.

@@ Variables not working in Synapse Dedicated SQL pool (@@error, @@rowcount, etc.,)

Any other ways to replace these parameters ??

Comment: What does "not working" mean? [@@ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) doesn't list Synapse in its "Applies To", but [@@ERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) does.

Comment: `@@error` -> embrace `TRY/CATCH` anyway, it is much more powerful and robust.

Comment: Please don't post "not working". It means nothing. Please post the actual error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Thom A said @@rowcount will not support by Azure Synapse. But @@error will support in Azure synapse.
Example:
Sample Code:

```
UPDATE Product.dbo
SET Name = 'Good'
WHERE id = 1
IF  @@ERROR = 547
BEGIN
    PRINT  N'A check constraint violation occurred.';
END

select * from Product.dbo
```

Output:

[image]

Alternative way of @@row count :

Run a query with query label using below code:

```
UPDATE Product.dbo
SET Name = 'Sugar'
OPTION (LABEL = 'QUERYID1');
```

Output:

[image]

Run below query to get the row count:

```
DECLARE @row_count int;
SELECT  top  1 @row_count = row_count
FROM sys.dm_pdw_request_steps s, sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests r
Where r.request_id = s.request_id
and row_count > -1
and r.[label] = 'QueryID1'
order  by r.[end_time] desc;
print @row_count
```

Output:

[image]

For more information you can refer this [document](https://dwgeek.com/azure-synapse-rowcount-alternative.html/#:%7E:text=The%20%40%40ROWCOUNT%20is%20one%20of%20the%20important%20system,statements.%20Azure%20Synapse%20does%20not%20support%20%40%40ROWCOUNT%20variable.).